# CSS Table layout with grouped cells?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have an application where I'm using CSS-based tables to create a grid, but some rows have children that are grouped inside of a div. Is there any way to use CSS to get the code shown at the bottom to display:

```
C   |CCCC|C
DDDD|D   |DDDDD
```

without changing the structure of the nodes?

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/soney/NRura/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   div.main { 
    display: table;
   }
   div.row {
    display: table-row;
   }
   div.cell {
    display: table-cell;
   }
   div.interfere {
    /* ??? */
   }
  </style>
    </head>
 <body>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">C</div>
    <div class="cell">|CCCC</div>
    <div class="cell">|C</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">DDDD</div>
    <div class="interfere">
     <div class="cell">|D</div>
     <div class="cell">|DDDDD</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I use the table tag to show you my solution? Or do you have to use divs and style them as a table using css?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck using divs

Answer (score 0):

I would assume :

.interfere {
   display:table-cell;
}

This will also work if you need the cells the same width :

div.row {
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.cell {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
div.interfere {
    display:inline;
}

Comment: Thanks, setting the cells to a fixed with does work in this particular case, but I'm looking for something that will work as the cells' contents' widths vary as well.